# Зачем делать лишний запрос?

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Меня убивает одна вещь. Когда я получаю откуда-нибудь не из БД модель (например со фронта пришла) полностью заполненную с id (уже сохранена) - я ее не могу просто так взять и сохранить, потому что она будет пытаться делать insert вместо update. Из-за этого приходится делать лишний select запрос чтобы получить эту же модель, но из БД. Вот в чем тут фишка и почему так по дурацки реализовано? Зачем нужен лишний select запрос?

пример

```
/**
 * Статья
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $author
 * @property string $text
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 */
class Article extends ActiveRecord {
    public static function tableName() {
        return '{{%article}}';
    }

    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className()
        ];
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            ['id', 'default', 'value' => null],
            [['user_id', 'name', 'author', 'text'], 'required']
        ];
    }
}

// где-то в контроллере
$article = new Article();
$article->load(Yii::$app->request->post()); // передано ['Article' => ['id' => 1, 'user_id' => '1', 'name' => 'name', 'author' => 'author', 'text' => 'text']]
$article->save(); // херакс ошибка, запрос insert вместо update, хотя Article с id = 1 уже есть в базе

// придется делать лишний запрос
$article = new Article();
$article->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
$article = Article::findOne($article->id);
$article->load(Yii::$app->request->post()); // еще раз загрузим, у нас же много ресурсов!!!
$article->save(); // вот теперь будет update
```

Comment: А теперь давай без эмоций лишних и с примерами кода что откуда где и как делаешь. Скорее всего ты делаешь не так

Comment: @АлексейШиманский просто я уже тут разобрался что любая модель (ActiveRecord) созданная через new, а не найденная через find будет делать insert всегда при вызове save. Даже с установленным id (PK) который уже есть в БД. Вот это выбешивает.

Comment: Либо ты предоставляешь необходимый код, данные и нормально адекватно сформулированный вопрос, чтобы выяснить как делать правильно,  либо можешь удалять его и продолжать дальше беситься и  считать, что делаешь всё правильно

Comment: Код будет или нет?

Comment: Сейчас напишу пример. Подождите.

Comment: Вообше это вопрос больше для github ;). Создайте issue.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно делать столько телодвижений. Вот пример функции контроллера ([источник](http://www.yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31855)):

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = Book::findOne($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&&$model->validate()) {
        $model->save(false); // Валидация проходит вызовом выше
        return  $this->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['book/index']));
    } else {
        return $this->render('bookUpdate', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```